# Move xfs journal from internal to external without losing data

Tags: linux, xfs

I have a big XFS filesystem containing about 3TB of data. This runs on some network device at our virtual server provider. We created it with the default settings, thus using an internal journal.

Because of the slow response of this device, I would like to try how it runs when the file system does not use the network device for the journal, but the faster connected ssd device.

Is there a way to "move" the XFS journal from internal to external without loosing the data?

Answer (score 1):

*Not* really.

In fact even simpler things like growing/shrinking the log section isn't still implemented yet. At least `man xfs_growfs` tells us so and trying to run it fails as promised:

```
xfs_growfs: log growth not supported yet
```

Comment: Appears that it should in fact support moving the journal. `mount -o ro,norecovery` and `xfs_growfs --help 2>&1 | grep external`.  See https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-change-an-xfs-journal-from-external-to-internal-if-the-external-log-is-gone-852550/

Comment: Thanks for letting know, I'll check it out and possibly correct the answer.